# Text doesn't fit in when user changes their phone font size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, responsive, text-size

All this is in Jetpack Compose
For example, I have a row with a defined size let's say width: 70.dp and height: 36.dp and lets say theres a text composable within that row with a text size 14.sp. Now if the phone users text size in their settings is set to minimum the whole text shows in that row but if they decide to change it to a bigger value the text gets cut of. How to combat this kind of issue? Any advice?

I tried looking for responsive text or something along the lines of that but all I see is information about responsive layout

Comment: Simple: Don't set hardcoded height and width. Build a responsive UI that scales nicely with those settings.